# Disable link in pdfkit rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink, pdfkit, disable-link

I am using [pdfkit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit) gem for generating the pdf file. I am using stylesheets for changing the style with

```
  pdf = PDFKit.new(html, orientation: 'Landscape')
  pdf.stylesheets << File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'assets', 'stylesheets', 'pdf.css')
```

In my `app/assets/stylesheets/pdf.css`, I have:

```
  a {
    cursor: default;
    color: black;
  }
```

In my html I have a simple `link_to` tag. I want to disable the link in the pdf, however, the above code makes the text of the link `black` but the cursor is still `pointer`. Also, I tried `pointer-events: none`. This also doesn't seem to work. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Note: I found similar issue in [this github issue](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/issues/87), but was not able to find an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and I was not able to find a perfect solution for this. This is a simple method I did and it worked...

```
<span class="show_in_html">
  <%= link_to(home_url) do %>
    <%=t('header.home')%>
  <% end %>
</span>

<span class="show_in_pdf">
   <%=t('header.home')%>
</span>
```

**In home.css**

.show_in_html{display:block}

.show_in_pdf{display:none;}

**In pdf.css**

.show_in_pdf{display:block !important;}

.show_in_html{display: none !important;}